# Is it possible to upgrade-insecure-requests only for request initiated by https

Tags: javascript, html, https

If the page is requested via http, then don't upgrade.

If the page is requested via https, then upgrade-insecure-requests to support mixed content.
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">`

Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want to use HTTP when HTTPS is more secure?

Comment: @Pseudohuman there are some 3rd-party libs not controlled, they add http content dynamically even when you specify https in the first place.